# UICollectionView deletion cells not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a 120 cells on my UICollectionView.  When my query finishes the end of its results, I call a function below:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:92 inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

    // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathFor];
    // [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths: index];

    // [self.collectionView.dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:index]; // First delete the item from you model
    // [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:index]]];
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    // Finished
}];
```

The above instead deletes nearly everything on screen. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should be using indexPathForItem:inSection: instead for a UICollectionView. Not sure whether this will fix your problem...

Comment: you probably need to update your model after deleting cells in your collectionview. Try to remove the data that was at the indexPath of your cell. This will ensure that reloeaddata won't bring you back to your old content.